# Прилипающее меню при скролле относительно элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок "header", в нем находится горизонтальное меню. На главной странице над блоком нет не каких других элементов, но внутри сайта размещаются блоки яндекс директа над "header". Нужно что-бы при скролле прилипало нав меню. Пытаюсь получить значение относительно документа, но, почему-то, не выходит

```
var windowTop = $('header').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if( $(window).width() >= '640' && windowTop <= '-194' ){
        $('header .menuBlock').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
    } else if ($(window).width() <= '640') {
        $('header .menuBlock').css({position: 'absolute'});
    } else {
        $('header').css({padding: '40px 0 0'});
        $('header .menuBlock').css({position: 'static'});
    }

});
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась. Значение переменной перенес в функцию и заработало. К сожалению, не понял с чем это связано

Comment: это связано с тем, что на каждое выстреливание события `scroll` значение `windowTop` будет другое. Вычислять его заранее - не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Igor да, точно. Моя невнимательность. Уже сам потом догадался. Спасибо